# In Python, is it preferred to declare local variables to extract data from an object, or to just deal with the object directly?

Tags: python, coding-style

For example, say you have an object Dog with 3 different string attributes (bark, sleep, eat). Also assume you have a function where you will be accessing these variables several times repeatedly (dog.bark, dog.bark, dog.sleep). Is it preferred to declare these at the beginning of the function (bark = dog.bark) or just use the dog object directly?

Example:

```
def print_dog_actions(dog):
    print dog.bark
    if dog.bark == 'loud':
       print 'dog bark is loud! {bark}'.format(bark=dog.bark)
    print dog.sleep
    print dog.eat 
    print dog.sleep + dog.eat
```

Versus:

```
def print_dog_actions(dog):
    bark = dog.bark
    sleep = dog.sleep
    eat = dog.eat
    print sleep
    print sleep + eat
    print bark + eat
```

May be a silly question, but I am having trouble finding what certain standards/conventions are in Python and this is just one of many questions I have.

Comment: First one is way to go!!

Comment: Those two codes don't do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the one that you will see more often, but it depends on what your overall goal is. But more often than not, you are going to want to do it this way.

I can't really think of a reason to do it the second way, other than sometimes it might make it more readable for you, if the variables get hairy.

Both ways are completely valid though. First way is more standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to use an attribute of the object, say `dog.bark`, more than once, then there is no point declaring an additional variable in order to do just one thing - except for readibility.

This question can lead onto memory management topics; take a look at the "heap" and the "stack" and how Python deals with storing variables.